# C# CodeDom generic add "out" parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I like to create a funktion which has a generic parameter:

public interface IInterfaceMethod<**out** T0> : 
        where T0 : IInterface2

So i created a new CodeTypeParameter and added this as constraint. So how can i create the "out" value?

Thanks

Comment: You can only *return* values of that type from this interface, either as the return value of getter-only properties or as return-values from methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can only put the `T0` generic type in "out" positions inside this interface:

- As the data type of a getter-only property
- As the data type of the return value of a method

You can not:

- Use the type as the data type for a property with a setter
- Use the type as the data type for a parameter (not even `out` parameters)

So this is an example of your interface:

```
public interface IInterfaceMethod<out T0>
    where T0 : IInterface2
{
    T0 GetterOnly { get; }
    T0 MethodReturnValue();
}
```

while this is illegal:

```
public interface IInterfaceMethod<out T0>
    where T0 : IInterface2
{
    T0 GetterAndSetter { get; set; }
    void MethodParameter(T0 value);
    void MethodOutParameter(out T0 value);
}
```